# Post a score to Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook

I just want to create a button in my iPhone game that will allow people to share their score to Facebook, when they complete a level.
How can I do it? Have I to use the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to use facebook mobile API for iPhone [found here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). The other way to do this is to create a web site optimized for mobile phones, implement the fb javascript API and embed the site in a UiWebView in your application. But this seems to me more complicated.